# How to select Max Value and add 1500 in total

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have Date, Vehicle No, Receipt No, Destination, Freight and Total columns in 'Crystal Report'. Now What I want to do is when Vehicle has one Destination it Just fetch simple Freight, When Vehicle has 2 Destinations it Select Max Freight from those Destinations and when Vehicle have 3 or more than 3 destinations, it select Max Freight and Add 1500 in it. 
Thank You

Comment: can you use SQL in Crystal reports?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Yes I can use SQL in Crystal Report. - Darren Wood

Comment: I have fetched whole data without total column. M. Schena